# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘streamlit_option_menu’ during streamlit deployment

Tags: python, machine-learning, deployment, data-science, streamlit

I encounter the following error during deployment, I have `streamlit_option_menu` installed and specified in my `requirement.txt` file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 556, in _run_script

    exec(code, module.__dict__)

  File "/app/nigeria-election2023-prediction/application.py", line 4, in <module>

    from streamlit_option_menu import option_menu

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'streamlit_option_menu'
```

Comment: `pip install streamlit-option-menu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means the **path** of `streamlit_option_menu` is different from the **path** of `application.py`

You can fix this by inserting the **path** of `streamlit_option_menu` in to your `application.py`

Before `from streamlit_option_menu import option_menu`

Copy the absolute path of `streamlit_option_menu`

Next step: In `application.py`

```py
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, "C:/past/your/coppied/path/here/streamlit_option_menu")

from streamlit_option_menu import option_menu
```